# How to create/edit/delete SQL server tables dynamically in asp.net web forms?

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, sql-server-2005, insert-update

I am using VS 2008 `(asp.net with c#)` and `SQL Server 2005`....

**Subject table:**

```
create table subject
(subid varchar(10),
subname varchar(20))
```

sample data:

```
subid           subname

1               subject1
2               subject2
3               subject3
```

=> it includes all the subjects' details in each row, for example:

**Result table:** Sampledata

```
studentid     subid        subname             marks

1             1            subject1            12
1             2            subject2            23
1             3            subject3            22
1             4            subject4            20
```

I want something like this:

```
studentid     subject1    subject2    subject3    subject4

1             12          23          22           20

2

3
```

So, I want to display each subject with its `marks in column wise`...

If I create a static table like...

```
create table subject    
(subject1 varchar(20),
 subject2 varchar(20),
 subject3 varchar(20))
```

**NOTE**:
Then it's not possible because the subjects might change per semester (in subject table).  That's why I want to create/edit/delete tables dynamically within an ASP.NET web form.

Comment: Yahia - i have created tables statically but i want to create it dynamically through asp.net web forms....

Comment: that does not answer any question I asked :-(

Comment: @mack28 it's not necessary to create dynamic tables for this.  You can get everything you need from the tables you listed, by using a *pivot* query.

Comment: dbaseman - i works when records changes dynamically ? and how can i use pivot query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things.  First, in the *results* table, the subject name is not necessary, and actually de-normalizes the database.  Should be like this:

```
studentid     subid        marks

1             1            12
1             2            23
1             3            22
1             4            20
```

Now, to query:

```
SELECT s.subjname, r.studentid, r.marks
FROM subject s
    INNER JOIN result r on s.subid = r.subid
```

To get the table you want, listing out each student's marks, use a pivot query like this:

```
SELECT studentid, 
[Subject1], [Subject2], [Subject3], [Subject4]
FROM
(SELECT s.subjname, r.studentid, r.marks
    FROM subject s
        INNER JOIN result r on s.subid = r.subid
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
AVG(marks)
FOR subjname IN ([Subject1], [Subject2], [Subject3], [Subject4])
) AS PivotTable;
```

You can make the pivot query dynamic as needed.  Not necessary to construct dynamic tables on the fly.

Comment: dbaseman - yes, it works for me to get results into columns...instead creating dynamic tables...thanks for guidence....